# Rails scope hash in array (json type)

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, json, activerecord, scope

I have a model **User** which has attribute **houses** (an array or hashes), how can I scope hash of houses by an **ID** so I can get **User** model with house ID = 1 for example?

Attribute houses is type: JSON

Database is MySQL

Here is example of model:

```
user: {
  "id": 1,
  "houses": [
    { "id": 1, "color" : "blue" },
    { "id": 2, "color" : "blue" }
  ]
}
```

I tried:

```
scope :houses_by_id, ->(id) { where("houses ->> id = ?", id) }
```

Comment: What type is `houses` in the database and which database? `jsonb` and PostgreSQL?

Comment: @muistooshort MySQL, json ( t.json :houses)

Comment: You should mention that in your question, everyone handles that sort of thing differently. Sorry, I don't know how it works in MySQL.

Comment: @muistooshort sure, i will edit question, thank you anyway

Comment: Does this mysql function (`json_contains`) help: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json-search-functions.html

Comment: @TarynEast contains return 0-1 i need to get scoped hash

Comment: But can you can use `json_contains` in your scope definition... to return the scoped hash that you need? You want to return a `user` that has `houses: id = 1` so you'd write a scope that returns the users if the json contains  houses: id = 1... yeah?

Comment: @TarynEast no, i need to scope user's attribute houses so in this case i get only 1 house instead of 2

Comment: so if the world were different and houses were also a model, you'd need to put the scope on the house model... but instead its in json. I don't think you can do this without writing yourself some possibly-nasty custom SQL function(s). unless theres some prewritten json-column SQL function that lets you d a "select" on key-value pairs from within the stored json object (which I'm not expert enough to know). I guess the question is: why is this not possible to do in the ruby once you've extracted the matching data from the db?